# Microsoft exchange rules - Double forwarding of e-mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have a question concerning forwarding rules in Microsoft Exchange.
We have a support team that needs to receive sms alerts when something is down at our customers.

Our setup is like this:

Alerts get sent by email to 1 mail address "alerts@dummy.com". In this e-mail address we have several rules to filter out the messages that need to be sent by text message. Those messages, we forward to "sms@dummy.com".

In the mailbox "sms@dummy.com" we added a rule that forwards all the messages that it receives to a mobile phone. However, this rule does not work correctly.

If we send a mail directly to "sms@dummy.com", the message is forwarded and we receive the text message.
If the mail comes from "alerts@dummy.com", nothing happens. The message is not forwarded.

Maybe this is by design by Microsoft? That a forwarded message can't be forwarded again to another mailbox?
Any idea how we can get the desired behaviour?

I know that we can modify the rules in "alerts@dummy.com" so that we add the sms recipient in the filtered rules so it gets forwarded directly. But then we need to add the mobile phone number in all the rules (about 10), which we want to prevent.

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Unfortunately, it seems that there is a limit on the number of times a mail can be redirected:

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx

"Number of times a message is redirected   The number of times a message will be redirected, forwarded, or replied to automatically based on Inbox rules. For example, User A has an Inbox rule that redirects messages to User B, based on the sender. User B has an Inbox rule that forwards messages to User C based on keywords in the subject line. If a message satisfies both of these conditions, the message is only sent to User B; it’s not forwarded to User C because only one redirection is allowed. In this case, the message is dropped without sending a non-delivery report (NDR) to User B indicating that the message wasn’t delivered to User C"

Comment: On the forwarded email who is the sender? I suspect the rules to send the sms are the problem.  I would adjust that rule to look for the subject that contains "FW:"

Comment: In the mailbox "sms@dummy.com" we forward all the mails, regardless of sender/subject... The sender of the original mail is another mail address (ex. scom@dummy.com).

Comment: I am saying adjust the rules to detect the subject.  Because the other triggering rules are clearly is being detected as something else.

Answer (score 1):

Emails are sent to alerts@dummy.com, these emails are then forwarded to sms@dummy.com, which then forwards these emails to a cell phone.

Email-->alerts@dummy.com-->sms@dummy.com-->cell phone

I'm assuming that alerts@dummy.com and sms@dummy.com are mailboxes. I have two suggestions:

1. Set up the forward to the cell phone in the mailbox properties of sms@dummy.com, not in the email client (I'm assuming Outlook). You'll need to have a Contact set up for the cell phone.
2. Delete the user account and mailbox for sms@dummy.com and create a Distribution Group for sms@dummy.com. Create a Contact for the cell phone and make it a member of the Distribution Group. Add any other mailboxes and/or Contacts that are needed to the Distribution Group.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestions. I'll look into it and see if this works.